# SQL query inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I want to modify a query in my forum code, to return two fields from a table tblProfile.  This table has the two fields, 'EmailAddress' and  'EmailVerified'.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 10 [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].thread_id, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].MESSAGE, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].message_date, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].show_signature, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].ip_addr, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].hide, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].author_id, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].username, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].homepage, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].location, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].no_of_posts, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].join_date, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].SIGNATURE, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].active, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].avatar, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].avatar_title, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].name 
                             AS groupname, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].stars, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].custom_stars, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGuestName].name 
                             AS guestname, 
                      Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 
                             [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].message_date ASC) 
                      AS 
                      rownum
        FROM   ([Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup] 
                INNER JOIN ([Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor] 
                INNER JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread] 

                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].author_id = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].author_id) 
                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].group_id = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].group_id) 
                LEFT JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGuestName] 
                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].thread_id = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGuestName].thread_id 
        WHERE


          [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].topic_id = 33854 
               AND ( [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].hide = 0 
                      OR [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].author_id = 13405 ))



                       AS 
       pagingquery 
WHERE  rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

I've got as far as selecting the fields:

```
 ,
 [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].EmailAddress, 
 [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].EmailVerified
```

But I'm a bit stuck on doing the join in that nest!

Any help appreciated!

### Edit

Sorry! I need to join tblProfile.UserID with tblAuthor.author_ID

Comment: What are the other fields of your `tblProfile` table?, so we can know how to join it with the other tables.

Comment: @Lamak Sorry!  I need to join tblProfile.UserID with tblAuthor.author_ID

Comment: @Abe yeah gosh im tired sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understood your query correctly, you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 10 [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].thread_id, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].MESSAGE, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].message_date, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].show_signature, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].ip_addr, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].hide, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].author_id, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].username, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].homepage, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].location, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].no_of_posts, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].join_date, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].SIGNATURE, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].active, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].avatar, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].avatar_title, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].name 
                             AS groupname, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].stars, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].custom_stars, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGuestName].name 
                             AS guestname, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].EmailAddress, 
                      [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].EmailVerified,
                      Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 
                             [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].message_date ASC) 
                      AS 
                      rownum
        FROM   [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup] 
                INNER JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor] 
                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGroup].group_id = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].group_id
                INNER JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread] 
                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].author_id = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].author_id
                LEFT JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGuestName] 
                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].thread_id = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumGuestName].thread_id 
                LEFT JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile]
                ON [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].UserID = [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumAuthor].author_ID
        WHERE [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].topic_id = 33854 
              AND ([Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].hide = 0 OR [Scirra].[dbo].[tblForumThread].author_id = 13405 )) AS pagingquery 
WHERE  rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a `JOIN` on tblProfile:

```
INNER JOIN [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile]   as tp
ON tblAuthor.author_ID  = tp.user_id
```

Without this there is no way to reference

```
 [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].EmailAddress, 
 [Scirra].[dbo].[tblProfile].EmailVerified
```

You can just put it anywhere after your tblForumAuthor `JOIN`

Comment: Abe thanks, but I'm stuck on where to put the join, I'm not very good at them and can't figure out for the life of me how to put it in with the others

Comment: Did you mean to say tblAuthor or were you trying to say tblForumAuthor above?  I ask because that table does not appear to be part of your query

Comment: yeah I do, sorry v tired tonight

Comment: Table names being right, I get `The multi-part identifier "Scirra.dbo.tblProfile.EmailAddress" could not be bound.`

Comment: thanks, other answer got it but +1 for your help, thanks again